# Ability to sort a concatenated formula field by numerical value

Tags: formula, formula-field, fields, massemailmessage

I have a formula field that concatenates values from various fields within a custom object. Each of these items has a simple numerical value. I've created this formula field to summarize certain items and have it appear in mail merge template we've designed.

I am trying to determine a way to sort this formula field by the value of each item in descending order. For instance 10 scarves, 5 letters, 4 socks.

Let me know if this is possible, formula code is below.

Thanks again.

```
SUBSTITUTE( 
IF(ISBLANK(Total_LettersTally__c),""," "&TEXT(Total_LettersTally__c) & " letters,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Gators__c),""," "&TEXT(Gators__c) & " Gators,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Paracords__c),"", " "&TEXT(Paracords__c) & " paracord bracelets,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Cool_Ties__c),"", " "&TEXT(Cool_Ties__c) & " cool ties,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Phone_Cards__c),"", " "&TEXT(Phone_Cards__c) & " phone cards,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Battalion_Buddy__c),"", " "&TEXT(Battalion_Buddy__c) & " battalion buddies,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Comic_Books__c),"", " "&TEXT(Comic_Books__c) & " comic books,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Handmade_Cards__c),"", " "&TEXT(Handmade_Cards__c) & " handmade cards,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Care_Kits__c),"", " "&TEXT(Care_Kits__c) & " care kits,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Gift_Cards__c),"", " "&TEXT(Gift_Cards__c) & " gift cards,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Socks__c),"", " "&TEXT(Socks__c) & " socks,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Girl_Scout_Cookies__c),"", " "&TEXT(Girl_Scout_Cookies__c) & " girl scout cookies,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Food_And_Snacks__c),"", " "&TEXT(Food_And_Snacks__c) & " food and snack items,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Toys_Animals_Bears__c),"", " "&TEXT(Toys_Animals_Bears__c)& " toys, animals And bears,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Beanie_Babies__c),"", " "&TEXT(Beanie_Babies__c)& " beanie babies,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Hats__c),"", " "&TEXT(Hats__c) & " hats," ) 
&IF(ISBLANK(Scarves__c),"", " "&TEXT(Scarves__c)& " scarves,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Video_Games__c),"", " "&TEXT(Video_Games__c)& " video games,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(CDs_DVDs__c),"", " "&TEXT(CDs_DVDs__c)& " CD's & DVD's,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Candy_lbs__c),"", " "&TEXT(Candy_lbs__c)& " lbs of candy,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Assorted_Items__c),"", " "&TEXT(Assorted_Items__c)& " assorted items,") 
&IF(ISBLANK(Recyclables__c),".", " "&TEXT(Recyclables__c)& " recyclable items,")& " ", 

",.", 

"" 
)
```

Comment: instead of keeping it as a formula field, it will be better to do the sorting & concatenating logic in a trigger and update a normal text field

Comment: This makes sense. I'm fairly new to triggers and am wondering how I could write such a trigger. I can definitely work with you to provide some details about our custom object and give you an idea of what we hope to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement can be fulfilled using a trigger.
The following `code snippet` can be used inside the trigger for the custom object records:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapNumValueAndFieldLabel = new Map<Integer,String>();
String strMessage;

//null checkers for the field and adding the number value as key and the string message as the value if its not null/blank/zero
IF(Total_LettersTally__c != null && Total_LettersTally__c != '' && Integer.valueOf(Total_LettersTally__c) != 0)
    mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.put(Integer.valueOf(Total_LettersTally__c), Total_LettersTally__c + " letters");

IF(Gators__c != null && Gators__c != '' && Integer.valueOf(Gators__c) != 0)
    mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.put(Integer.valueOf(Gators__c), Gators__c + " Gators");

IF(Paracords__c != null && Paracords__c != '' && Integer.valueOf(Paracords__c) != 0)
    mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.put(Integer.valueOf(Paracords__c), Paracords__c + " paracord bracelets");

//and so on for other fields....

//Proceed further only if either of the fields have non zero values 
if(mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.values().size() > 0)
{
    List<Integer> lstNumValue = new List<integer> ();
    lstNumValue.addAll(mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.keyset());

    //Sort the Values (by default SFDC sorts it in ascending order)
    lstNumValue.sort();

    //Iterating through the sorted Integer list in reverse order (descending) to get the final String message from the map 
    for(Integer i = lstNumValue.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        strMessage = mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.get(lstNumValue(i)) + ", ";
    }
}

//strMessage will hold the message you want to display
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.